# How I can output Craft Commerces Stripes Publishable Key in a template

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce

I would like to know how I can output Craft Commerces Stripes Publishable Key, which I define under Payment Methods, in a template?

The value I set is settings[publishableKey].

Thanks
Stefan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
{% if cart.paymentMethod.class == 'Stripe' %}
    {{ cart.paymentMethod.settings.publishableKey }}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Thanks. Works like a charm. Is this documented somewhere?

Comment: I'm not sure. I just checked the payment method model + the database.